# Imacro Delete only the cookies (Not CLEAR)?

Tags: imacros

I need a methode to delete all Cookies but dont delete Hystory and Cache.

The Background is:
My problem is that my Imacro Script needs a Firefox configuration that is not Default, but uses CLEAR to delete cookies, and CLEAR resets the configuration to default.

Is there a way to solve my Problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using [the JavaScript Scripting Interface](http://wiki.imacros.net/Firefox#Javascript_Scripting_Interface) in 'iMacros' for Firefox, the following code may be helpful:

```
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm");
var allCoookies = Services.cookies;
allCoookies.removeAll();
```

Comment: @macroscripts  <   Why not?

Comment: Can you delete specific cookies? The above method worked for me but unfortunately in my case i have some cookies i need to keep. Anynway to only delete specific cookies? Ive tried using `getCookiesFromHost(domain)` , however I'm getting an empty object when I do that.

Comment: @dranieri, yes. 'iMacros for Firefox' can do what you need.